# Why is there blank space to the right of appointments and to the left of events in Outlook 2010 Calendar?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I notice that when I add an appointment to my calendar, there is some blank space to the right of the box containing the text of the appointment.  When I add an event, there is some blank space to the left.  Can somebody explain the purpose of these blank spaces? The image below shows examples of what I mean:[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no experience with Outlook, but I know it from Google Calendar.

The space is there so you can drag or click next to an existing event. Let's say you had an all-day event (pink below) and wanted to add your lunch break, then you'd have no way to mark a time during the all-day event if you didn't have the small margin.

[image]

This, of course, is assuming Outlook also has this drag-to-create feature. If that's not the case, please let me know.

Comment: That is how Outlook functions as well.

Comment: Looks like that explains it for appointments.  Any idea about the space to the left of events?

Comment: I think that's just there for stylistic purposes, because Outlook always leaves a blank space at the bottom of the day header for you to add new all-day events.  It may also be to help separate events between days.  If they abutted each other at the edge of the day, you wouldn't be able to tell which handle you had if you were trying to change how many days the event covered.

Comment: I accepted this answer because it arrived first, even though it did not answer the entire question.  The other half of the question was answered by CharlieRB.  Because I can't accept two answers, I upvoted his answer.

Answer (score 2):

I can tell you the space to the left is to indicate how the time is shown. For instance, if you select to show the time as `Free` there will be a white edge on the left, striped for `Tentative` and purple for `Out of Office`, while `Busy` gives no edge.

Select `Out of Office`:
[image]

will result in this:
[image]

I have not been able to figure out why there is space to the right of appointments. The only other thing I found when searching for it was your post in the [Microsoft Office Community](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-outlook/why-is-there-blank-space-to-the-right-of/dc528a1e-5140-4105-bf4e-d72c728c18e6).

Comment: This answers the other half of my question, so I upvoted it.  Were it possible, I'd accept both responses.  (Regarding the MS Office Community, it's interesting to note that in the 13.5 hours since I posted my question there, there have been a total of 3 views and no responses.  Clearly superuser is the much more effective forum.)